# load text file using ssis and split it with header trailer and detail

Tags: ssis

I have one text file which has header,detail and trailer 
I want to separate this information and header information goes to header table, detail information goes to detail table and trailer information goes to trailer table. how I can do this using ssis?

Answer (score 0):

A flat file connection can be told to skip a certain number of header rows, but there's no way to specify anything about trailer rows.

This would have to be done using a script task.